# Integral transform that resembles the Fourier transform.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

I would like to take the following integral.

$$ F(k):= \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{ikf(x)} g(x) dx$$

Where $g(x) \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})\cap L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f(x)$ is an arbitrary fucntion.

Questions

1. Are there general methods for computing such a transform? For example, if $f(x):= x^{n}$  is anything known? More generally for $f(x) : = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}$ is anything known? Any nice formulas etc.
2. Due to the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma we know that when $f(x):= x$,
   $F(k) \rightarrow 0$  as $|k| \rightarrow \infty$. Is there a similar result for certain families of functions $f(x)$?

Comment: If you're satisfied by asymptotics as $k \to \infty$ this is exactly the integral to which the stationary phase approximation applies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation Physicists use a certain asymptotic expansion of this integral in terms of Feynman diagrams that you could look up.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you very much for your comment. Stationary phase approximation is just what I was looking for. Now, any chance you know if $F(k)$ is in $L^{1}$ and or $L^{2}$?